# Learn Bunch-Kaufman factorization

Tags: soft-question, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Does anyone know a good reference to learn the Bunch-Kaufman factorization? I've been looking a while there are some references, but somehow they assume that you do know nothing on matrix algorithms.

I am looking for a reference for laymen, where ideally a few examples are given, just to get the feel of how it works.

I intend to use the method for matrix inversion on a symmetric real matrix.

Comment: What about [the original paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4da6/c2eb9dbb881f9e686f70c0ef931af43f0412.pdf)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've liked [this](http://oz.nthu.edu.tw/%7Ed947207/Chap13_GE3) reference. It goes through the original 1977 paper with some additional explanations / details. Here's a [seminar/workshop](http://oz.nthu.edu.tw/%7Ed947207/) webpage with additional PDF references for elimination-type algorithms (hit-or-miss on English translations...). Chapter 13 corresponds to the first reference, and Chapter 14 corresponds to further variants on the original BK factorization.

Comment: This helps a lot!